# Web Forms Inline Code Begin Tags

Tags: asp.net, .net

I just wan to to know why these different begin tags exist, if there are still more and if they can be used interchangeably:

```
<%# Do.Something() %>
<%= Do.Something() %>
...
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The tags do different things.  For example `<%= %>` will write the result of the expression within the tags to the output, while `<%# %>` will use data-binding expressions to reference data from a data source.  A fuller explanation can be found at http://weblogs.asp.net/ahmedmoosa/archive/2010/10/06/embedded-code-and-inline-server-tags.aspx